# Php, how to get parameters / arguments of method EXCATLY written in source?

Tags: php

Im looking for the way to retrieve the arguments of method with reflection. But I need them exactly how they were written, so not in array

EDIT: ok here what I tried:

```
public function myParams (array &arg)
```

.

```
$ref = new ReflectionMethod ('MyClass', 'myParams');
$ref->getParameters()
```

this returns somewhat:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => &
    object(ReflectionParameter)[27]
      public 'name' => string 'myParams' (length=5)
```

and, noticed that & character in parameters? If I remove it, I get the same result. I simply want to get a `array &arg` string

Comment: What's wrong with the array `func_get_args` returns? Why can't you use the array?

Comment: Since you haven't made an effort to solve the problem yourself, I assume you're willing to pay others to do your work. What's your budget?

Comment: @ceejayoz this returns with the parameters of the self-method.... I need other method

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking and why `func_get_args` isn't what you're searching for. Maybe some code why this isn't working for you?

Comment: I edited the thread, sorry for not being clear

Comment: [`ReflectionParameter::isPassedByReference()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.ispassedbyreference.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `array` is a primitive type, that's why you don't get the type hint out of the box. But you could still check manually.

```
class B {}
class A { public function myParams (array &$arg, B $b, $i = 0, $c) {} }

$ref = new ReflectionMethod ('A', 'myParams');
$params = $ref->getParameters();

foreach($params as $param)
{
    if($param->isArray())
    {
        echo "{$param->name} is of type Array.\n";
    }

    if($param->isPassedByReference())
    {
        echo "{$param->name} is passed by reference.\n";
    }

    if($param->getClass() !== null)
    {
        echo "{$param->name} is of class {$param->getClass()->name}.\n";
    }

    if($param->isDefaultValueAvailable())
    {
        echo "{$param->name} has a default value of {$param->getDefaultValue()}.\n";
    }

    if(!$param->isArray() && !$param->getClass() && !$param->isDefaultValueAvailable())
    {
        echo "{$param->name} is of unknonwn type.\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
arg is of type Array.  
arg is passed by reference.  
b is of class B. 
i has a default value of 0.
c is of unknonwn type.
```